# How to include html file in another html file and then alert result via javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Am trying to include html file in another html file and then alert result.

I found a solution here.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file)
Please how do I alert the content of **b.html** instead of calling it in div.
something like

```
alert('b.html content here');
```

**a.html:**

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
    <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#includedContent").load("b.html"); 
alert('b.html content here');
    });
    </script> 
  </head> 

  <body> 
     <div id="includedContent"></div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

**b.html:**

```
<p>This is my include file</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery has a handy function for getting other webpages, [`$.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/):

```js
$.get('b.html', function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

`function(data) {}` is a callback which runs when the http request is made successfully, and `data` will contain the response body.